# Android OnTouch simultaneous touches

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener

I have an OnTouchListener in my activity and it's set on a layout and 5 other buttons, if you press them one by one/alone they work perfectly but if I want to press a button down and still move my finger on the layout it won't work until I release my finger from the button.
How can I use OnTouch so it will be possible to use a few views at the same time?

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.layout:

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                // On click on screen
                oldX = (int) event.getX(); // set first click X as old
                oldY = (int) event.getY(); // set first click Y as old
                isClicked = true;
                return true;
            }

            else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                isClicked = false;

                // On finger move on screen
                newX = (int) event.getX(); // set current X
                newY = (int) event.getY(); // set current Y

                diff[0] = newX - oldX; // Set X difference
                diff[1] = newY - oldY; // Set y difference

                oldX = newX; // set current X as last X
                oldY = newY; // set current Y as last Y

                // Send to server
                new UDP_handler(IPAddr, port).execute("MOVE|" + diff[0] + "," + diff[1]);

                return true;
            }

            else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                if (isClicked)
                    new UDP_handler(IPAddr, port).execute("CLICK|LC");
                return true;    
            }

            break;

        case R.id.Button0:
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                new UDP_handler(IPAddr, port).execute("CLICK|MUP");
                return true;    
            }
            break;

        case R.id.Button1:
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                new UDP_handler(IPAddr, port).execute("CLICKUP|LC");
                return true;    
            }
            else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                new UDP_handler(IPAddr, port).execute("CLICKDOWN|LC");
                return true;    
            }
            break;

        case R.id.Button2:
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                new UDP_handler(IPAddr, port).execute("CLICK|MC");
                return true;
            }
            break;

        case R.id.Button3:
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                new UDP_handler(IPAddr, port).execute("CLICK|RC");
                return true;
            }
            break;

        case R.id.Button4:
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                new UDP_handler(IPAddr, port).execute("CLICK|MDOWN");
                return true;    
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

(I want to press down R.id.button1 and move my finger on R.id.layout at the same time going through it's down and up actions as well)

Comment: Maybe use GestureOverlay ?

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski I can't figure out how to use it the way I had in the onTouch function